# Access a prop of Vuex store dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

Is it possible to enter a Vuex store state with another variable?
For example:

```
export const TestState = {
 state: {
  data: {
   test: {
    value: 0,
   }
  }
 },
 mutations: {
  Mutation123(state, message) {
   var CanbusSignal = "Test123";
   state.data.test.value = message.topic.CanbusSignal;
  }
 }
}
```

This doesn't work ofcourse.
In the code above, it enters `message.topic.CanbusSignal` My goal is to enter `message.topic.Test123`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you wish to access a prop of `message.topic` dynamically?
If so it should look like this:

```
var CanbusSignal = "Test123";
state.data.test.value = message.topic[CanbusSignal];
```